# How do I make the 'panel/well' dynamically wrap around the image while keeping it centered? // Using Bootswatch/Bootstrap CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row" align="center">
                <div class="panel panel-default" align="center">
                    <div id="<?php echo $main_content ?>" class="panel-heading">MY-HEADING-HERE</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                                My image/"timelapse" that utilizes 'jquery.innerfade.js' here. (VIEW THE SEPARATE CODE SNIPPET BELOW)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The above code is a snippet of the timelapse page on my first website I'm working on: [www.interjo.in/timelapse](http://www.interjo.in/timelapse) (if you want to check out the live example, you have to sign in. Use these credentials: username-stackoverflow, password-1234)

Whenever someone goes to this page (/timelapse), and if their window is not fullscreen [making the window smaller] the image/timelapse snaps to the left, and doesn't stay in the middle where I'd want it to be.

How can I keep it at the center?
How can I also keep the panel wrap the image dynamically even though the window resizes. the `containerheight: '480px'` below  only allows for a fixed value, so when the window resizes, the size of the panel doesn't change, keeping it looking awkward :/

The code below is between the `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div>` in the code above.
The images's/timelapse's css styling is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="LOCATION OF 'jquery.innerfade.js'"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
        function(){
            $('div.CUSTOM-CLASS').innerfade({
                speed: 0,
                timeout: 100,
                type: 'sequence',
                containerheight: '480px'
            });
        });
    </script>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="CUSTOM-CLASS">
        <?php FOREACH LOOP HERE ?>
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="IMG-SOURCE">
        <?php ENDFOREACH ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the long post, can't "wrap" my mind around this -.-'

Also, I'm beginning to feel as though a javascript script to create the timelapse isn't going to be ideal in the future, so I was thinking of somehow creating a video every ime it updates? Not sure how though. If you have any ideas as to where I can do such a thing please do tell! Right now I'm looking at a [youtube API type script](http://www.mattparkinson.eu/auto-timelapse-youtube/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding `col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3` to your wrapper div `<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">`.

So that in end you have that code:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <div class="CUSTOM-CLASS">
        <?php FOREACH LOOP HERE ?>
            <img class="img-thumbnail" src="IMG-SOURCE">
        <?php ENDFOREACH ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), to fully understand the implications of `.col-xs-    .col-sm-    .col-md-    .col-lg-`.

For your second question, I'm not sure what would be the best approach, but I just noticed that my browser (chrome) got seriously laggy while I had your timelapse site open for a few seconds..

Comment: Nice, that seems to work better [on my 1280x1024 screen]. Thanks! But when I switch go fullscreen on my 1080p screen, the image is slightly falling to the left. its weird cuz it works great when viewed on mobile and on my smaller 1280x1024 screen. `<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-offset-3"></div>` I tried centering that code, as that was the element that Chrome highlighted for me that was sticking to the left side. But could not, for some odd reason.

Comment: It's not weird. It's just that you give the div a declaration of `width: 50%` if you use bootstrap like this. And if you use a larger screen, the 50% gets bigger that your actual content width, and therefore the content gets aligned left in the bigger div. You have to center your content within the div somehow. I can't play with your project site, since the non-stop image flickering slows my browser extremely down an makes it impossible for me to use the developer tools. Sorry.